# Diving into gsoap, Makefile.am of examples in ubuntu pkg,

Tags: gsoap

hi
i find it quite hard to get gsoap running.
Need to mention my knowledge of C/C++ is quite limited.

In /usr/share/doc/gsoap/ i see

Makefile.c_rules
Makefile.cpp_rules
Makefile.defines

In /usr/share/doc/gsoap/examples :
the README says just make but there is only Makefile.am

So i did make -f Makefile.am

examples/ck$ make -f Makefile.am
/usr/bin/soapcpp2 -I/soapcpp2/import ck.h

and then all the source code is created.

And then??
What is the application?

For my project i just need a WS client, but i guess i better create a server too so i can test it with it.

Hope my question is clear enough.. :-/
greets, florian

Comment: i accept the answer from Christian as it is correct. I knew it already but had various problems on the way and ended up in the Makefile i posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490110/c-class-declaration-and-include-issues-in-gsoap-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Header File `ck.h` contains the functions from your service. The gSoap compiler soapcpp2 creates the stubs and skeletons. To create a test-server you can view the documentation on how to create a [standalone server](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc7.2.3). If you compile your standalone-server you will get undefined references because you have to implement the functions from your ck.h file. Take a look at the [example](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc7.2.1) from the gSoap documentation. The `calc.h` file represents your `ck.h` file. There is also a [quick start](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc1.2) guide for developing a client and server.